# Complex NSDictionary. Taken objectsforkeys and sorting them as NSArray or separate variables?

Tags: objective-c, xml, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an NSDictionary that was converted from XML that is really confusing me.  If you could take a look and let me know the best method of getting the objects for the key class_id, I would really appreciate it.

```
 {
     response=  {
        "@status" = ok;
        rosters =         {
                     "@page" = 1;
                     "@page_count" = 1;
                     "@records_per_page" = 50;
                     "@total_record_count" = 8;
                     roster =               (
                                            {
                                       "@class_id" = 0001;
                                       "@role" = 0;
                                       "@user_id" = 12345;
                                       class=                  {
                                                                "@active" = false;
                                                                "@name" = NAME;
                                                               }
                                            }
                                            {
                                       "@class_id" = 0002;
                                       "@role" = 0;
                                       "@user_id" = 12345;
                                            }
                                            {
                                       "@class_id" = 0003;
                                       "@role" = 0;
                                       "@user_id" = 12345;
                                            }
                                            );
                             }
                 }
}
```

All I am wanting to do is either set up variables for the individual class_id's or put all of the class_id's in an NSArray.  I've been reading the apple documentation and have tried every method I can think of, but it either crashes with nsexception or returns no data.  Thanks so much for your help.

Ok let's just backup a minute.  It would appear that the XMLReader plugin that I used to convert this to an NSDictionary is making this far more complicated than it needs to be.  Here is the original XML data.

```
<response status="ok">
<rosters page_count="1" page="1" records_per_page="50" total_record_count="7">
<roster class_id="0001" role="S" user_id="91563" roster_id="ID"/>
<roster class_id="0002" role="S" user_id="91563" roster_id="ID"/>
<roster class_id="0003" role="S" user_id="91563" roster_id="ID"/>
<roster class_id="0004" role="S" user_id="91563" roster_id="ID"/>
<roster class_id="0005" role="S" user_id="91563" roster_id="ID"/>
<roster class_id="0006" role="S" user_id="91563" roster_id="ID"/>
<roster class_id="0007" role="S" user_id="91563" roster_id="ID"/>
</rosters>
</response>
```

Can anyone suggest a simple way to just grab the class_id values?  Is converting to NSDictionary a reasonable way to do it?  I just need the data as separate variables or an NSArray.

Comment: Unfortunately the '@' character in your key names makes it a little more of a pain than it otherwise would be. Otherwise, if this were your dictionary, you could do: `NSArray* classIDs = [resposne_dict valueForKeyPath:@"response.rosters.roster.class_id];`. If you have more than one roster in rosters, it would come back as an array of arrays.

Comment: @JasonCoco maybe he could escape the @ characters to do what he wants?  ala `NSArray* classIDs = [response_dict valueForKeyPath:@"response.rosters.roster.\@class_id];` ???

Comment: @MichaelDautermann It's possible, but I wasn't sure and couldn't look it up, which is why I responded in a comment. If you're in a position to verify, I suggest you do so and write up the answer ;)

Comment: nawww... I've got real work to do.  Somebody else can get the credit (how about you?)

Comment: @michael how about I test out your code and you agree to help me if I get stuck?  But I almost definitely will get stuck which is why i would really like an answer

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Or is there a better way to convert xml to NSDictionary that doesn't use the @ character for the keys?  I was using the plugin found [here](https://github.com/Insert-Witty-Name/XML-to-NSDictionary)

Comment: If you don't get an official answer in a few hours, I might take another stab at this.  :-)

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Ok I added the original xml data.  Due to how complicated it got when I converted to an NSDictionary I'm thinking there is a much easier way to do this, I just don't know how.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about the "best method".  Just use a method that won't be confusing to revisit later and lets you move on to more important things.

```
NSMutableArray *classIds = [NSMutableArray array];
NSDictionary *rosterArray = [convertedXmlDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"response.rosters.roster"];
for (NSDictionary *roster in rosterArray) {
    [classIds addObject:[roster objectForKey:@"@class_id"]];
}
```

Comment: Ok, I hate to do this to you, but I'm stuck.  I added another layer to the coverteddictionary above and I can't figure out how to access "name".  If I set "class" up as an NSMutableArray then I can't access the "name" because objectForKey is not an NSArray method.  Does that make sense?

Comment: nevermind I got it by using valueforkeypath:@"response.rosters.roster.class"  Thanks