# Convert NSMutableArray to NSDictionary in order to use objectForKey?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an NSMutableArray that looks like this

```
 {
    "@active" = false;
    "@name" = NAME1;
 },
 {
    "@active" = false;
    "@name" = NAME2;
 }
```

Is there a way to convert this to an NSDictionary and then use objectForKey to get an array of the name objects?  How else can I get these objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a even shorter form then this proposed by Hubert

```
NSArray *allNames = [array valueForKey:@"name"];
```

`valueForKey:` on NSArray returns a new array by sending `valueForKey:givenKey` to all it elements.

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCIBCDJ):

> `valueForKey:`
>   Returns an array containing the results of invoking
>   `valueForKey:` using `key` on each of the array's objects.
>
> `- (id)valueForKey:(NSString *)key`
>
> **Parameters**
>   `key` The key to retrieve.
>
> **Return Value**
>   The value of the retrieved key.
>
> **Discussion**
>   The returned array contains `NSNull` elements for each object that returns `nil`.

Example:

```
NSArray *array = @[@{ @"active": @NO,@"name": @"Alice"},
                   @{ @"active": @NO,@"name": @"Bob"}];

NSLog(@"%@\n%@", array, [array valueForKey:@"name"]);
```

result:

```
(
        {
        active = 0;
        name = Alice;
    },
        {
        active = 0;
        name = Bob;
    }
)
(
    Alice,
    Bob
)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to convert NSMutableArray to corresponding NSDictionary, just simply use mutableCopy

```
NSMutableArray *phone_list; //your Array
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
dictionary = [phone_list mutableCopy];
```

Comment: best solution by far

Comment: This... doesn't work. Your `dictionary` variable here will actually be an array.

Answer (score 3):

This is an Array of Dictionary objects, so to get the values you would:

```
[[myArray objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"name"]; //Replace index with the index you want and/or the key.
```

Comment: I'm assuming you meant valueForKey:@"@name", but I tried this and it throws NSUnknownKeyException.  I made this array from an nsdictionary so it may not be set up as an "Array of Dictionary objects" I didn't think I had any other option.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751198/complex-nsdictionary-taken-objectsforkeys-and-sorting-them-as-nsarray-or-separa)

Comment: I figured it out and set it up as an NSDictionary instead of NSArray.  Thanks

Comment: There is even a shorter form, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can

see this example:

```
NSDictionary *responseDictionary = [[request responseString] JSONValue];
NSMutableArray *dict = [responseDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
NSDictionary *entry = [dict objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *num = [entry objectForKey:@"num"]; 
NSString *name = [entry objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *score = [entry objectForKey:@"score"];
```

im sorry if i can't elaborate much because i am also working on something

but i hope that can help you. :)

Comment: @Davis G. - i guess Hubert's answer is much simpler and easy to use.

Comment: @vikingosegundo - sir hi.. can you help me out in a cocos2d i have problem i had question ban thats why i cant post questions i really need help can you please?

Comment: What is a question ban? and no, I have no experience with cocos2d.

Answer (score 1):

**This is example one of the exmple get the emplyee list NSMutableArray and create NSMutableDictionary.......**

```
NSMutableArray *emloyees = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"saman",@"Ruchira",@"Rukshan",@"ishan",@"Harsha",@"Ghihan",@"Lakmali",@"Dasuni", nil];

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSString *word in emloyees) {
    NSString *firstLetter = [[word substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString];
    letterList  = [dict objectForKey:firstLetter];

    if (!letterList) {
        letterList = [NSMutableArray array];
        [dict setObject:letterList forKey:firstLetter];
    }
    [letterList addObject:word];
}   NSLog(@"dic %@",dict);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, guys.... the problem is that you are stepping on the KeyValue Mechanism in cocoa.

KeyValueCoding specifies that the @count symbol can be used in a keyPath....

myArray.@count

SOOOOOO.... just switch to the ObjectForKey and your ok!

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"theValue", @"@name", nil];

id kvoReturnedObject = [myDictionary valueForKey:@"@name"]; //WON'T WORK, the @ symbol is special in the valueForKey
id dictionaryReturnedObject = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"@name"];

NSLog(@"object = %@", dictionaryReturnedObject);
```